# How to show qtips in cytoscape on two nodes at the same time on mouseover a node?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, qtip2

I'm using cytoscape.js for creating a graph. Each node in the graph has some features that I'm trying to show as a tip using qtip.

I want to show qtip on two nodes at the same time: one node is the target node that generates mouseover event and the other node's reference can be attained by getElementById method.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the show event for each qtip to a custom event, like `showqtip`.  Then do `node.emit('showqtip')`.  Make sure your options for qtip allow for showing more than one qtip at a time (e.g. `single: false`) by setting the qtip options appropriately: http://qtip2.com/options